# How to manually evaluate a parameter estimate using the first few values of a time series?

Tags: time-series, self-study, estimation, autoregressive

I'm working on a problem (I paraphrase),

> Consider the $\text{AR}(2)$ model $$y_t=\alpha y_{t-1}-(1-\alpha)y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t, \hspace{1em} \epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2).$$ The conditional least squares likelihood estimate of $\alpha$ satisfies $$\hat{\alpha}=\frac{\sum_{t=3}^ny_ty_{t-1}+\sum_{t=3}^ny_ty_{t-2}+\sum_{t=3}^ny_{t-2}^2+\sum_{t=3}^ny_{t-1}y_{t-2}}{\sum_{t=3}^ny_{t-1}^2+\sum_{t=3}^ny_{t-2}^2+2\sum_{t=3}^ny_{t-1}y_{t-2}}.$$ If $y_1=1,y_2=2,y_3=0,y_4=1$, calculate the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\alpha}$ of $\alpha$.

I don't know how the first few values of $y_t$ allow me to evaluate the whole expression for $\hat{\alpha}$, which includes $y_t,t\geq5$. Could someone give me a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These first few values may be your entire sample. Where do you see the expression for $\hat\alpha$ including $y_t,t\geq 5$? I only see $t=n$, and you can set $n=4$.

Comment: Like this?
\begin{align}
\hat{\alpha}_{t\in[1,4]}
& = \frac{(y_3y_2+y_4y_3)+(y_3y_1+y_4y_2)+(y_1^2+y_2^2)+(y_2y_1+y_3y_2)}{(y_2^2+y_3^2)+(y_1^2+y_2^2)+2(y_2y_1+y_3y_2)} \\
& = \frac{(0+0)+(0+2)+(1+4)+(2+0)}{(4+0)+(1+4)+2(2+0)} \\
& = \frac{9}{13}
\end{align}

Comment: The first equality looks correct. I have not checked the second or third ones.

Comment: OK, thanks. Would you mind confirming or disconfirming my impression that evaluating $\hat{\alpha}$ for general $n$, given a finite specified sample, is difficult or impossible? If so, that increases my confidence that calculating $\hat{\alpha}_{t\in[1,4]}$ is the right approach.

Comment: @mjc, I am not sure what you mean. If you are given a finite specified sample, there is no point in considering a general $n$, since $n$ is given. And you will always use a finite sample (what else could you do?), so that is always the case. But the equation works for any $n\geq 3$, so it is general.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I wanted to check because I've also come across infinite expressions, e.g. infinite moving average representation of an AR process, so I didn't have finite datasets firmly in mind as a default.

Comment: @mjc, I understand. (And even so, a *model* with an infinite number of parameters and a *sample* with an infinite number of observations are different domains.)